# Prove that $yx = qxy$ implies $(x + y)^d = x^d + y^d.$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, noncommutative-algebra, roots-of-unity

Here is the question I am trying to prove:

Let $q\ne1$ be a root of unity of order $d > 1.$ Prove that $yx = qxy$
in a noncommutative algebra implies $$(x + y)^d = x^d + y^d.$$

I do know how to tackle it, could someone help me please?

**Some attempts:**

1-$(x + y)^2 = (x + y)(x + y) = x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 = x^2 + xy + qxy + y^2$ but I do not know how the expression $xy + qxy$ should be removed in this case ..... can anyone explain this to me please?

2- Also, $$(x + y)^3$$$$ = (x + y)^2(x + y) $$$$= (x + y)(x + y)(x + y)$$
$$ = (x^2 + xy + yx + y^2) (x + y) $$$$= (x^3 + qx^2y + q^2x^2y + q^2xy^2 + x^2y + xy^2 + qxy^2 + y^3)$$

but I do not know how the expression between $x^3$ and $y^3$ should be removed in this case … can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: First try to multiply out $(x+y)^d$ for $d=2$ and see what you get. Then try it for $d=3$. Show your work in your question.

Comment: @coffeemath OP obviously means a  noncommutative algebra over $\mathbb C$, not working within $\mathbb C$ itself.

Comment: Try to determine a general  formula for $(x+y)^d$ for any number $q.$ You will have to introduce generalized binomial coefficients. Then conclude the desired formula in the case of roots of unity.

Comment: @Somos will do in some hours

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc how can I check the case of roots of unity ..... I do not know.

Comment: The 2nd root of unity is $-1$. The 3rd root of unity $q$ satisfies $q^3=1$.

Comment: @Emptymind A $d$-th primitive root of unity (for $d>1$) makes a certain polynomial of degree $d-1$ equal to $0$, but no other similar polynomial factors that you will find in those $q$-binomial coefficients that you will have to introduce.

Comment: What  q-binomial coefficients I should introduce? I know many of them, which ones?

Comment: To finish the case of your work for $d = 2$, note $xy + qxy = (1+q)xy = 0$ since $q = - 1$ is the only nontrivial second root of unity

Comment: @Somos why the second root of unity is $-1$? I do not understand this.

Comment: @Emptymind For $d=2$ "of order $d>1$" it has to be $-1$ since the only other second root of unity is $1$ which has order $1$.

Comment: @Somos how do you find the roots of unity in general in case of q-binomials?

Comment: @Emptymind Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity for what are roots of unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}_qx^{n-k}y^k \quad(*)$$ for some coefficients ${n\choose k}_q.$
Clearly ${n\choose 0}_q={n\choose n}_q=1.$ We will derive a recurrence relation for these quantities. By definition we have $$(x+y)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose k}_qx^{n+1-k}y^k$$ On the other hand
$$(x+y)^{n+1}=(x+y)^n(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}_qx^{n-k}y^k(x+y)\\ =
\sum_{k=0}^n q^k{n\choose k}_qx^{n+1-k}y^k+\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}_qx^{n-k}y^{k+1}\\ =\sum_{k=0}^n q^k{n\choose k}_qx^{n+1-k}y^k+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n\choose k-1}_qx^{n+1-k}y^{k}\\
=x^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left [{n\choose k-1}_q+q^k{n\choose k}_q\right ]x^{n+1-k}y^k+y^{n+1}
$$ Therefore  we obtain
$${n+1\choose k}_q={n\choose k-1}_q+q^k{n\choose k}_q\quad (**)$$
Basing on $(**)$ it can be shown, by induction on $n,$ that  if $q^k\neq 1$ for $1\le k\le n-1$ then
$${n\choose k}_q={(1-q^n)(1-q^{n-1})\ldots (1-q^{n-k+1})\over (1-q^k)(1-q^{k-1})\ldots (1-q)}\quad (***)$$
If $q$ is a primitive root of unity of order $d,$ i.e. $q^d=1$ and $q^k\neq 1$ for $1\le k<d,$  then $(***) $ implies
$${d\choose k}_q=0,\quad 1\le k\le d-1$$
as $1-q^k\neq 0$ for $0<k<d$ and $1-q^d=0.$
Hence putting $n:=d$ in  $(*)$ gives $$(x+y)^d=x^d+y^d$$
If $q$ is a non-primitive root of order $d$, the conclusion does not hold. For example if $d=2d_0$ and $q$ is a primitive root of unity of order $d_0,$ then $$(x+y)^{d}=[(x+y)^{d_0}]^2=(x^{d_0}+y^{d_0})^2 \\ = x^d+y^d+x^{d_0}y^{d_0}+y^{d_0}x^{d_0}\\ =x^d+y^d+x^{d_0}y^{d_0}+(q^{d_0})^{d_0}x^{d_0}y^{d_0}\\ =
x^d+y^d+2x^{d_0}y^{d_0}$$
Concerning $q$-binomial coefficients [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145219/discussion-on-answer-by-ryszard-szwarc-prove-that-yx-qxy-implies-x-yd); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.